# I dont understand the use of private access modifier

Tags: java, oop

The Argument given is to prevent access from outsiders? Who are the outsiders?

1. Hackers?
2. People using your code (eg. Working in Teams)

and, does it benefits an individual programmer not part of any team? eg. like accidentally modifying program state.

Comment: Who (what book, what documentation) gave that argument?

Comment: The whole point of encapsulation is to protect "future us" from making mistakes.
If it makes logical sense (in your code) to allow public access to a variable, then go ahead.

Comment: @ernest_k: " One of OOP’s primary tenets is to prevent outsiders from gaining unauthorized access to data, and it accomplishes that by encapsulating data and cordoning off ideas into silos. "  Source: https://careerkarma.com/blog/functional-programming-vs-oop/

Comment: @ernest_k Again, " Using the private modifier is the main way that an object encapsulates itself and hides data from the outside world "

What is the outside world...can someone elaborate?

Comment: Well, you need to take those statements with a measure of caution. Access modifiers prevent code (others' or yours) accessing your class's private members from compiling. This is roughly the best you get. Securing your code (from hacking) is a completely different story. And as for "other" people, start with the fact that those other people can access your source code. If they can't, then we're back to the preceding point: all you get is that your private members are inaccessible to other classes (at compile time). Books/tutorials need to be more specific.

Comment: @ernest_k " Access modifiers prevent code (others' or yours) accessing your class's private members from compiling. "

Why would I want that?

Comment: It is not about the hackers. these private access modifier will help you when you have a big system.

Comment: Well, that's what you get :). Now seriously, I gave you the most direct result of encapsulating class members. As for "why" would one want to do that, your tutorials gave reasons already. In short: the class is a unit, with intimate knowledge of its object. If another class (possibly written by someone else or by yourself after context switch) is allowed to easily change data in it, bad things (like bugs) start to happen. There's a reason classes expose public contracts, but to keep these public contracts, some internal behavior must remain unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example to help you understand** 
suppose you want to make a game in which you have a class Player which has health and you want to add or reduce health depending on what the player does

something like this:

```
 class Player {
    public String name;
    public int health = 100;

    public void addHealth(int amount) {
        if(health + amount <= 100){
            health = health + amount;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid amount");
        }
    }

    public void reduceHealth(int amount) {
        if(health - amount >= 0){
            health = health - amount;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid amount");
        }

    }
}
```

now, if you keep the health field as public then you can change the health anytime you want by doing something like this

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player pl1 = new Player();
        pl1.health = 50;
    }
}
```

this is because you have set health to public but if you set health to private then you cannot directly change it. 
you will have to call some public methods like addHealth() or reduceHealth() to change the value of health. this is also beneficial because you can add verification in those methods say, to make sure that health does not exceed 100 or go below 0. 
but if you make health public then you may end up changing it to a wrong value by mistake and then your game will have bugs.

You will realize the importance of encapsulation in time

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, because I'm still a student. The private access will basically block the client from directly changing the instance variables in a class. You can search up what client means in java, but the definition of a client: is an entity that requests a service from another entity (ex: from class to a class) without being worried about how it got that service from the entity.